# PHP based database table "viewer" with filtering and export abilities, specifically for data viewing and reporting purposes?

Tags: php, database, filter

Before I re-invent the wheel, I was hoping someone knew of a popular PHP based database table "viewer" with configurable per-column filtering by enumerated values and includes export abilities. Ideally, this would be a tool for data exploring/viewing/reporting purposes.

edit -- i seem to be angering people... My apologies. Yes, i searched google first, then stack overflow, then both again with different terms.

This is what Im looking for:

something we could call along the lines of "tableview.php" and pass $_REQUEST the following:

- table name
- filter column names (would be used to filter the contents of the page - enumeration of values would occur on load)
- subcolumns that would be visible in a modal or pop-in only when you click on a row
- export to csv, pdf, xls, etc

Comment: Yes. For literally every database *ever*. You could maybe *say* what DBMS you're looking at, or you could just go google it because that's where the answers are going to come from anyway.

Comment: Do you know [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/)?

Comment: I googled it and found nothing like what I was looking for - sorry if I'm retarded. PHPMyAdmin looks to be for administrators - I don't want to expose anywhere near the amount of functionality/power PHPMyAdmin exposes.

Comment: It's a pity some people here rush to down-vote. Your question and the response helped me find phpgrid, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! And I don't agree that this is off topic - this does relate to programming, it's basically asking for a suitable programming library for displaying database tables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure you are looking for [this](http://www.phpgrid.org)

see the demo [here](http://www.phpgrid.org/demo-center/)

Comment: Yep. This is it. Thanks so much! Would upvote, but can't...